# Images now shown in WordPress Media Library

Tags: php, wordpress, image, media

I've added 3 subfolders in the wp-content/uploads/2017 folder, but when i try to access them in the admin dashboard, they're not displayed. Why ?

Comment: thanks for like my answer. In future if you have any query then directly post on isparkz.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not accessed due to file permissions.Change the folder permission to 755 or 777.